# Show all elements within div?

Tags: jquery, html

My code looks like this:

`<div id="div1">
      <span id="span1"></span>
      <span id="span2"></span>
      <span id="span3"></span>
</div>`

I used these jquery commands:

`$('#span1').hide()

$('#span2').hide()`


Now I want to unhide all the elements within div1.

How can I do that? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$('div#div1 span').show();
```

Which would show each span inside the div with id='div1'.

Or, if the div contains things which aren't spans, you can use:

```
$('div#div1').children().show();
```

Comment: I would clarify that this solution shows all `<span>` elements in the div; to show all elements in the div (assuming that there may be children other than span elements), use `$('div#div1 > *).show();`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much. (I'll put a check on your answer when I'm allowed to - in 8 minutes.)

Comment: @Ken, I was just in the process of typing a more general answer, your way works too. Theres is almost always a bunch of different ways to select things in JQuery.

Comment: going deeper... `$('#this_div').show().find('*').children().show();` (i just searched for this answer for the last 25 minutes, btw)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('span[id*="span"]').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> $('#div1 span').show();

or whole document

> $('span').show();